# Udp transmission handling - delay is unavoidable?

Tags: connection, udp, delay

I use UDP (via WIFI network) to transmit packages (car's velocity information) from PC to car's controller. However, while transferring, there is always delay: maximum is even 1 second. Whether i have bug is UDP connection implementation so that delays exist?

Besides, is there any way to reserve bandwidth for that connection so that no delay exists?

If delays are unavoidable, how can i skip old packages in receiving buffer and just get the latest one?

My system is as following:
 1. Server:  Camera + PC that detects car's position and calculate it's velocity.
 2. Client:  Car that receives it's velocity from PC then adjust it's velocity via its PID controller.

Comment: Well, what kind of link do you have to the car?

Comment: I've edited. I use wifi network for transmission.